# Is painted shoe molding more expensive than stained shoe molding?

Tags: hardwood-floor

Long story short: contractors did all the shoe molding stained to match the floor when I said I wanted it to match the trim. Now he's telling me that "painted shoe molding is more expensive" - hundreds more - but I have a feeling he's just trying to cover the cost of his mistake.

Is painted shoe molding more expensive?

Comment: I would say painted shoe molding is cheaper as it is generally made out of wood species that isn't readily looked to for staining (pine for instance). Just do a search on big box stores for bare wood (like oak) vs painted to get an idea of the cost.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is about the same unless you are using gold paint.   Both require a couple coats, and my opinion is nail holes easier to cover when painting.

Also you are right in making sure the shoe molding matches trim.   It is ultra awkward when it matches the floor.  (however if it is a new floor you shouldn't have to have shoe molding at all)

My take is get a quote for just the molding from someone local - see if there is a difference.   Take it to your contractor.   He didn't do the job.   So you take that amount off the bill or he does it.   It is that easy.

Comment: Respectfully disagree with the blanket statement that a new floor shouldn't have shoe. We don't know if the base was new/old, and we don't know what kind of floor it is.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - the width of the baseboard can provide enough of an expansion gap for almost every type of floor - so new or old it wouldn't need it if preplanned correctly.